# how to get value out of promise into an array in protractor

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, end-to-end

I have created a function for getting all links and clicking on them and then handle the windows using another method. Everything works fine, but now I want to put a condition that only few links are clicked. So the function is like:

```
this.getLinks = function(){
    browser.driver.findElements(that.links).then(function(foundElements){
        var val;
        for(var i =0;i<foundElements.length;i++){
            browser.sleep(3000);
            foundElements[i].getText().then(function(textValue){
                val = textValue;
                **console.log(val);**  
            });
            if(val != '??????' || val != '?????????' || val != '??????'){
                foundElements[i].click();
                that.getWindows();
             }
           }
        });
     };
```

I want to get the value of **val** out of promise so that I can put a condition  that only selected links are clicked.

Comment: Any reason you're using `browser.driver.findElements` and `browser.sleep`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) to filter out elements based on the text value and [`each()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) to apply a function to each element of the filtered elements:

```
this.getLinks = function() {
    element.all(that.links).filter(function(elm) {
        return elm.getText().then(function (val) {
            return val != '??????' || val != '?????????' || val != '??????';
        });
    }).each(function (elm) {
        elm.click();
    });
};
```

Comment: I have tried the above flow but all links was clicked instead of selected one. And when i check the value of val using console.log I m not getting the correct values. Means instead of 6 values i m getting only 4 and click is working for all links.

Comment: @user1320675 this should work in theory, I have no way to reproduce your problem. Where have you put `console.log(val);` and what have you got on the console? Thanks.

Comment: return elm.getText().then(function(val){                                                                                  console.log(val);     return val != '??????'     });    I m putting console.log(val) just where i ll get the value of it in return function.

Comment: @user1320675 okay, so, inside the "then" function. What do you get on the console?

Comment: I m getting all values including the one which I have put condition on while return like return val != '?????' || val != '????' || val != '?????'. I want remaining values except the above mentioned three, so that click only on them.